# How to fetch data from a piece of json file

Tags: python, json

I have multiple piece text from json
For example

```
{"citationID":"a1u01nqrgpa","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[2]","plainCitation":"[2]","noteIndex":0},"citationItems":[{"id":44,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/VR3UIAUH"],"uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/VR3UIAUH"],"itemData":{"id":44,"type":"article-journal","title":"Bacillus subtilis and its relatives: molecular biological and industrial workhorses","container-title":"Trends in biotechnology","page":"247–256","volume":"10","source":"Google Scholar","title-short":"Bacillus subtilis and its relatives","author":[{"family":"Harwood","given":"Colin R."}],"issued":{"date-parts":[["1992"]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"} 

{"citationID":"a2k9krb4sun","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[7]","plainCitation":"[7]","noteIndex":0},"citationItems":[{"id":76,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/KAHC7LAC"],"uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/KAHC7LAC"],"itemData":{"id":76,"type":"article-journal","title":"Development of Pgrac100-based expression vectors allowing high protein production levels in Bacillus subtilis and relatively low basal expression in Escherichia coli","container-title":"Microbial Cell Factories","volume":"14","issue":"1","source":"Crossref","URL":"http://www.microbialcellfactories.com/content/14/1/72","DOI":"10.1186/s12934-015-0255-z","ISSN":"1475-2859","language":"en","author":[{"family":"Phan","given":"Trang Thi Phuong"},{"family":"Tran","given":"Linh Thuoc"},{"family":"Schumann","given":"Wolfgang"},{"family":"Nguyen","given":"Hoang Duc"}],"issued":{"date-parts":[["2015",12]]},"accessed":{"date-parts":[["2018",12,14]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"} 

{"citationID":"a13g93on8ud","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[6]","plainCitation":"[6]","noteIndex":0},"citationItems":[{"id":75,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/WN9Q3G27"],"uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/WN9Q3G27"],"itemData":{"id":75,"type":"article-journal","title":"Construction of a 5′-controllable stabilizing element (CoSE) for over-production of heterologous proteins at high levels in Bacillus subtilis","container-title":"Journal of Biotechnology","page":"32-39","volume":"168","issue":"1","source":"Crossref","DOI":"10.1016/j.jbiotec.2013.07.031","ISSN":"01681656","language":"en","author":[{"family":"Phan","given":"Trang Thi Phuong"},{"family":"Nguyen","given":"Hoang Duc"},{"family":"Schumann","given":"Wolfgang"}],"issued":{"date-parts":[["2013",10]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"} 

{"citationID":"ajlpfebik","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[13]","plainCitation":"[13]","noteIndex":0},"citationItems":[{"id":6,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/IWPBWYVL"],"uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/IWPBWYVL"],"itemData":{"id":6,"type":"article-journal","title":"Use of the Escherichia coli lac repressor and operator to control gene expression in Bacillus subtilis","container-title":"Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences","page":"439-443","volume":"81","issue":"2","source":"www.pnas.org","abstract":"The Escherichia coli lac operator has been placed on the 3' side of the promoter for the penicillinase gene of Bacillus licheniformis, creating a hybrid promoter controllable by the E. coli lac repressor. The E. coli lac repressor gene has been placed under the control of a promoter and ribosome-binding site that allows expression in Bacillus subtilis. When the penicillinase gene that contains the lac operator is expressed in B. subtilis on a plasmid that also produces the lac repressor, the expression of the penicillinase gene can be modulated by isopropyl beta-D-thiogalactoside (IPTG), an inducer of the lac operon in E. coli. A similar system was constructed from a promoter of the B. subtilis phage SPO-1 and the leukocyte interferon A gene, which allowed the controlled expression of interferon in B. subtilis. These two examples show that a functional control system can be introduced into B. subtilis from E. coli.","ISSN":"0027-8424, 1091-6490","note":"PMID: 6420789","journalAbbreviation":"PNAS","language":"en","author":[{"family":"Yansura","given":"D. G."},{"family":"Henner","given":"D. J."}],"issued":{"date-parts":[["1984",1,1]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"}
```

I need to fetch title (4 titles) from each piece of json.

I tried this code

```
import json
import uuid

with open('1.json') as f:
    contents = json.load(f)
i = 0
while i < 25:
        i += 1
        if 'title' in contents['citationItems'][$i]['itemData']:
                print 'title    = ' + '"' + contents['citationItems'][0]['itemData']['title'] + '",'
```

But failed to get result
Error:

```
  File "stack.py", line 9
    if 'title' in contents['citationItems'][$i]['itemData']:
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I need result like

```
title    = "a"
title    = "b"
title    = "c"
title    = "d"
```

Comment: You do not need `$` use just `i`

Comment: In addition to Rakesh's comment, if I understand correctly, there is no need for a while loop. Instead just do print(contents['citationItems'][0]['itemData']['title']) (tested in Python3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write in pythonic way like :

```
if 'title' in contents['citationItems'][i]['itemData']:
   print 'title    = ' + '"' + contents['citationItems'][0]['itemData']['title'] + '",'
```

remove **"$"** from `if 'title' in contents['citationItems'][$i]['itemData']:`
 condition

EDIT:

Create json file like:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {"citationID":"a1u01nqrgpa","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[2]","plainCitation":"[2]",
        "noteIndex":0},"citationItems":[{"id":44,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/VR3UIAUH"],
            "uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/VR3UIAUH"],"itemData":{"id":44,"type":"article-journal",
                "title":"Bacillus subtilis and its relatives: molecular biological and industrial workhorses","container-title"
                :"Trends in biotechnology","page":"247–256","volume":"10","source":"Google Scholar","title-short":
                "Bacillus subtilis and its relatives","author":[{"family":"Harwood","given":"Colin R."}],
                "issued":{"date-parts":[["1992"]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"} ,

{"citationID":"a2k9krb4sun","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[7]","plainCitation":"[7]","noteIndex":0},
"citationItems":[{"id":76,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/KAHC7LAC"],"uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/KAHC7LAC"],"itemData":{"id":76,"type":"article-journal","title":"Development of Pgrac100-based expression vectors allowing high protein production levels in Bacillus subtilis and relatively low basal expression in Escherichia coli","container-title":"Microbial Cell Factories","volume":"14","issue":"1","source":"Crossref","URL":"http://www.microbialcellfactories.com/content/14/1/72","DOI":"10.1186/s12934-015-0255-z","ISSN":"1475-2859","language":"en","author":[{"family":"Phan","given":"Trang Thi Phuong"},{"family":"Tran","given":"Linh Thuoc"},{"family":"Schumann","given":"Wolfgang"},{"family":"Nguyen","given":"Hoang Duc"}],"issued":{"date-parts":[["2015",12]]},"accessed":{"date-parts":[["2018",12,14]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"} ,

{"citationID":"a13g93on8ud","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[6]","plainCitation":"[6]","noteIndex":0},
"citationItems":[{"id":75,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/WN9Q3G27"],"uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/WN9Q3G27"],"itemData":{"id":75,"type":"article-journal","title":"Construction of a 5′-controllable stabilizing element (CoSE) for over-production of heterologous proteins at high levels in Bacillus subtilis","container-title":"Journal of Biotechnology","page":"32-39","volume":"168","issue":"1","source":"Crossref","DOI":"10.1016/j.jbiotec.2013.07.031","ISSN":"01681656","language":"en","author":[{"family":"Phan","given":"Trang Thi Phuong"},{"family":"Nguyen","given":"Hoang Duc"},{"family":"Schumann","given":"Wolfgang"}],"issued":{"date-parts":[["2013",10]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"} ,

{"citationID":"ajlpfebik","properties":{"formattedCitation":"[13]","plainCitation":"[13]","noteIndex":0},
"citationItems":[{"id":6,"uris":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/IWPBWYVL"],
    "uri":["http://zotero.org/users/local/sIEziHS8/items/IWPBWYVL"],"itemData":{"id":6,"type":"article-journal",
        "title":"Use of the Escherichia coli lac repressor and operator to control gene expression in Bacillus subtilis","container-title":"Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences","page":"439-443","volume":"81","issue":"2","source":"www.pnas.org","abstract":"The Escherichia coli lac operator has been placed on the 3' side of the promoter for the penicillinase gene of Bacillus licheniformis, creating a hybrid promoter controllable by the E. coli lac repressor. The E. coli lac repressor gene has been placed under the control of a promoter and ribosome-binding site that allows expression in Bacillus subtilis. When the penicillinase gene that contains the lac operator is expressed in B. subtilis on a plasmid that also produces the lac repressor, the expression of the penicillinase gene can be modulated by isopropyl beta-D-thiogalactoside (IPTG), an inducer of the lac operon in E. coli. A similar system was constructed from a promoter of the B. subtilis phage SPO-1 and the leukocyte interferon A gene, which allowed the controlled expression of interferon in B. subtilis. These two examples show that a functional control system can be introduced into B. subtilis from E. coli.","ISSN":"0027-8424, 1091-6490","note":"PMID: 6420789","journalAbbreviation":"PNAS","language":"en","author":[{"family":"Yansura","given":"D. G."},{"family":"Henner","given":"D. J."}],"issued":{"date-parts":[["1984",1,1]]}}}],"schema":"https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"} 
]
}
```

And change .py file :

```
import json
import uuid

with open('1.json') as f:
    contents = json.load(f)

for data in contents['data']:
    if 'title' in data['citationItems'][0]['itemData']:
        print('title    = ' + '"' + data['citationItems'][0]['itemData']['title'] + '",')
```

O/P

```
title    = "Bacillus subtilis and its relatives: molecular biological and industrial workhorses",
title    = "Development of Pgrac100-based expression vectors allowing high protein production levels in Bacillus subtilis and relatively low basal expression in Escherichia coli",
title    = "Construction of a 5′-controllable stabilizing element (CoSE) for over-production of heterologous proteins at high levels in Bacillus subtilis",
title    = "Use of the Escherichia coli lac repressor and operator to control gene expression in Bacillus subtilis",
```

Comment: I got error message like this ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 5, in <module>
    contents = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 - line 7 column 1809 (char 736 - 4509)```,  i am using version Python 2.7.12

Comment: @sam Please share your json file

Comment: I already share the content (4 lines)  .json file, save the text as 1.json. stack can't  me to share a file.

Answer (score 0):

Python tends to prefer a simpler path. We don't have `$` for variables, that's a shell script thing (inherited by Perl and PHP). We generally avoid indices for iteration. And doing an extra check instead of failing is error prone, as we can see where you used `$i` and `0` seemingly for the same thing. Furthermore, [format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) support hierarchical references.

```
for citationItem in contents['citationItems']:
    print('title     = "{0[itemData][title]}"'.format(citationItem))
```

If we might encounter a citationItem lacking a title, skipping it is easier with an exception:

```
for citationItem in contents['citationItems']:
    try:
        print('title     = "{0[itemData][title]}"'.format(citationItem))
    except KeyError:
        pass
```